# Error message when working in vb.net with datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have already read a lot of forums. Actually, none of them answered my question. The problem fires when I run the process second time. There is no problem when I run the program first time

I call windows form from main menu:

```
Private Sub ProjectsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProjectsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    SqlStatement1 = "Select TOP(1) fiscalyear From " & ConfigTable & " Order By fiscalyear DESC"
    FiscalYear = GetData(SqlStatement1, 0)
    frmCPProjectInfo.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Form's frmCPProjectInfo Load event calls following sub:

```
    SqlStatement = "Select p.projtitle, p.projectid, d.deptid, p.deptrank, p.account, SUBSTRING(p.account, 6, 4) As last4 From (Select dept01.*, f.funddesc, f.fund_num From (Select * From "
    SqlStatement &= DepartmentsTable & " Where deptid In (Select deptid From " & WorkAreaTable & " Where userlogin = '" & CurrentUser & "')) dept01 LEFT OUTER JOIN " & FundsTable
    SqlStatement &= " f On dept01.fund = f.fund) d LEFT OUTER JOIN " & ProjectInfoTable & " p On p.deptid = d.deptid Where p.FiscalYear = " & FiscalYear & " Order by deptid, projectid"
    frmCPSelectProject.ShowDialog()
    LoadAll()
    cmdDeleteProject.Image = ListOfImages.Images(0)
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(cmdDeleteProject, "Delete Project")
```

In here, LoadAll() displays the project.

In form  frmCPSelectProject load event calls following sub:

```
  Sub DisplayAll()
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connStringCIP)
    Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand
    Dim drCIP As SqlDataReader
    Dim dtCIP As DataTable = New DataTable

    sqlConn.Open()
    sqlCom = New SqlCommand(SqlStatement, sqlConn)
    drCIP = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
    dtCIP.Load(drCIP)
    If dtCIP.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is no record to show")
        NoRec = True
        dtCIP.Dispose()
        drCIP.Dispose()
        sqlCom.Dispose()
        sqlConn.Close()
        sqlConn.Dispose()
        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtCIP
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 300
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 85
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 85
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width = 85
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Width = 140
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Width = 250

    dtCIP.Dispose()
    drCIP.Dispose()
    sqlCom.Dispose()
    sqlConn.Close()
    sqlConn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Then, I select the project an execute following routine:

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdContinue.Click
    SelectID(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
End Sub

Sub SelectID(ByVal NewInd)
    Dim DeptID As String
    Dim DeptRank As String

    ProjectID = DataGridView1.Rows(RowInd).Cells(1).Value
    DeptID = Trim(Str(DataGridView1.Rows(RowInd).Cells(2).Value))
    DeptRank = Trim(Str(DataGridView1.Rows(RowInd).Cells(3).Value))
    Select Case Order
        Case "projtitle"
            SearchBy = "projtitle"
            SearchItem = DataGridView1.Rows(RowInd).Cells(0).Value
        Case "account"
            SearchBy = "account"
            SearchItem = DataGridView1.Rows(RowInd).Cells(4).Value
    End Select

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

After that, the routine LoadAll()  (see above) executes.

The problem is that if I close form frmCPProjectInfo going back to main menu and then run the process again, I get an error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The program stops on the line
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 300 (see DisplayAll() above).
Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have already read a lot of forums. Actually, non of them didn't answer my question. Like I said, the problem fires when I run the process second time. What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` == true?

Comment: Thank you, lomed. It works. How can I rate your reply?

Comment: Another time... glad I helped!

Comment: Also, I found other way to solve this problem. Before I used "Fill" for AutoSizeColumnsMode. When I switch to "AllSells", the problem was gone.